# Question on completion of a measures

Tags: measure-theory

I am stuck on the the following part of proving the completion of a measure: Suppose we have that sets $A,B,A',B'$ in the $\sigma$-algebra, and $E$ some arbitrary set such that
$$ A \subset E \subset B \ ; \ A' \subset E \subset B' $$
with $\mu(B\setminus A) = 0 = \mu(B'\setminus A')$. Then, I want to show that $\mu(A) = \mu(A')$.

I have tried looking up related questions, but those utilize the symmetric difference of sets instead.

Comment: $\mu (A) \le \mu (E)\leq \mu (B')\le \mu (B'\setminus A')+\mu(A')=\mu(A')$.